# Photoshop CS4, my line tool is now drawing arrows, how do I put back to default and what is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've just learnt how to draw curves in photoshop, after doing this my lines started disappearing first of all and now i'm getting arrows instead of straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

Select the Line tool. You'll see a tool bar option called "Geometry Options" (it looks like a down arrow next to the Custom Shape tool).

Select Geometry Options and you'll see the Arrowheads options.

This will only affect new lines, not existing ones.