# Photoshop CS6: Line tool prints arrow instead of line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I'm trying to draw a basic line, but instead it draws an arrow shape.

I select the Line Tool from the toolbar. I set up its fill and stroke colors and thickness. I simply try to draw a line with it. But it prints an arrow instead of a line.

I switch to Custom Shape Tool and select an object (e.g.; a rabbit). When I return back to the Line Tool, it still draws an arrow. So I guess it is independent with the shape selected in the Custom Shape Tool.

I don't see a Geometry Option in the toolbar, so [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/142287/95347) doesn't help me in Photoshop CS6.

How do I make the line tool draw lines?

**EDIT**: I don't see this horizontal toolbar:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This thing has been giving me a headache too!  I finally found the answer myself.

Do you see the arrow drop-down menu next to the Custom Shape tool?  There is a check box for Start and End.  Uncheck them both, and it will draw a line instead of an arrow!

Answer (score 21):

If you're looking for the arrowhead options, it's located on the gear (default position):
[image: Arrowheads]

If that doesn't work, try to reset the line tool:
[image: Reset Tool]

Answer (score 0):

With line tool selected go top left screen and click drop down arrow next to line image.  Then click settings and click Reset tool.